# To find underutilized instances list based on CPU and network utilization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cost-management, aws-cost-explorer

I would like to get all the AWS EC2 instances list which are idle and underutilized. I need to filter them based on CPU utilization used less than 2% and network I/O less than 5Mb for last 30 days.

Can you please provide me with the commands or any scripts to get the list or guide me to get that achieved.

I need this to get that list and terminate those instances for cost management.

Comment: These metrics are available in Amazon CloudWatch Metrics. It can even give you some pretty graphs showing the data.

Answer (score 0):

> You can create a CloudWatch alarm that is triggered when the average
> CPU utilization percentage has been lower than 2 percent for 24 hours,
> signaling that it is idle and no longer in use. You can adjust the
> threshold, duration, and period to suit your needs, plus you can add
> an SNS notification so that you will receive an email when the alarm
> is triggered.

Kindly refer to this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/UsingAlarmActions.html#AddingStopActions:%7E:text=Create%20alarm.-,Adding%20terminate%20actions%20to%20Amazon%20CloudWatch%20alarms,-You%20can%20create) to create an alarm to terminate an idle instance using the Amazon CloudWatch console.